How can I "ApplyDescription()" locally?
I want to make a cutscene system in Roblox Studio by loading in the player's character locally onto a dummy in the Workspace before anything else; an identical clone (same RigType, avatar proportions, etc.) of the player character is what I want but the only problem is that I can't use
ApplyDescription()

from the client, and it won't be multiplayer-friendly if I use the server because I'm pretty sure it'll either break from not being able to choose a player or use one player's character and it won't look good for the others. How can I achieve this?
TLDR: How can I make a Dummy in Workspace look like each player's character only for themselves in Roblox Studio?
Here is the LocalScript I tried to use from StarterPlayerScripts:
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local rig = workspace:WaitForChild("Rig")
local humanoid = rig:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

task.wait(10)
local desc = players:GetHumanoidDescriptionFromUserId(game.Players.LocalPlayer.UserId)
humanoid:ApplyDescription(desc)

I was expecting it to work without any problem. After the wait, the script should work, right?
No, of course not. ApplyDescription() can only be called by the backend server.

I already tried using this function after I posted this, but thanks anyway. I was able to accomplish my goal as wanted by going back and forth with the clients and server using RemoteEvents.

Rig:CreateHumanoidModelFromUserId(UserID)
--Make this the dummy would be best way

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
